# Change domain class cache setting outside of domain class

Tags: caching, grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

I have a plugin that has a bunch of domain classes. This plugin is used by multiple applications.

My problem is that I can't specify the mapping->cache setting in the domain classes themselves (as they need to have different values depending up the application that uses them). For example, in Application A, I'd like to have domain class X read-only cached, and domain class Y not cached. In Application B, I'd like to have domain class X transactional cached, and domain class Y read-only cached.

What I'd like (I'm hoping this is already available) is something like:

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping { cache true }
```

But instead of being global, I can apply to just a specific domain class, something like:

```
grails.gorm.com.integralblue.domain.User.mapping { cache true }
```

---

Someone had suggested having each domain class checking the grails config, something like:

```
static mapping = {
    cache: Holders.grailsApplication.config.com.package.Person.cache ?: false
}
```

And the Config:

```
com.package.Person.cache = true
```

but I'd like to avoid that if possible

Thanks!

Comment: Why do want to avoid that approach?

Comment: It sucks to make changes to the domain classes in this plugin and re-release them to other projects, and also it means other projects with other classes will need to do the same caching modifications, and it ends up being a big hassle.  So if I can avoid that it would be great.  Not necessarily a technical reason, more of a bureaucratic one.

Answer (score 0):

The approach which you have mentioned should be used in the ideal case scenario.
I agree that changes has to be made in the plugin and the application as well.

Ideally, domain classes in the plugin should provide a lenient mapping which can be overriden.

If you have used `grails.gorm.default.mapping { cache true }` in the plugin or `cache: true` or which ever mapping in the domain class, then it can easliy be overriden in the application according to need. For example:

```
//Domain class in Plugin
class Person{
   static mapping = {
      cache: 'read-only'
   }
}
```

Since mapping is nothing but a static block in a groovy object it can easily by metaClassed in concerned application at runtime like

```
//Application A:
Person.metaClass.'static'.mapping = {
    cache 'transactional'
}

//Application B:
Person.metaClass.'static'.mapping = {
    cache 'read-write'
}
```

*(Untested)*
If you want to do the same thing collectively for all the domain classes then the domain class artefact can be used as below

```
//Application A BootStrap
grailsApplication.domainClasses.each{
    it.clazz.metaClass.'static'.mapping = {cache 'transactional'}
}
```

selectively:

```
//Application A BootStrap
def personClazz = 
     grailsApplication.domainClasses.find{it.clazz.simpleName == 'Person'}.clazz
personClazz .metaClass.'static'.mapping = {cache 'transactional'}
```

*Either of the cases you have to do some modification in Applications using the plugin.

Comment: Will this override the existing mapping block or will it append?

Comment: This will override, yes you have to specify all the mappings @AlexBeardsley .

Comment: Also does bootstrap run before grails looks at the mappings and does stuff with it?  I'm actually unfamiliar with the order of how things are executed.

Comment: @AlexBeardsley Yes bootstrap runs on app startup. I am highly doubtful on appending to `mapping`, I can see if that can be an option. Again, this is an error prone route, you do not want to mess with the existing mapping. I just gave you a work around, your suggested route should be tried.

Comment: I'm messing with it now, and it looks like bootstrap's init happens way after grails does its thing with the domain classes, so changes to the block aren't having any effect.  Even trying to change it at runtime with some dummy service doesn't change the caching behavior.